# Question about role of the trailing[0] in np.nonzero(arr)[0]

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([True, True, False, True, False])

a = np.nonzero(arr)
b = np.nonzero(arr)[0]
```

output for `a`:

```
(array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

output for `b`

```
[0 1 3]
```

Question:  Unlike the output for **a**, why does the [0] cause the output for  **b** to include only the array and not the dtype?

Comment: `a` does not include the dtype when printed on my machine.  What is your `np.version.version`?  Mine is 1.15.4.

Comment: It is  1.16.4,  used in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most python containers, including `tuple`, use `repr` to display their elements, regardless of whether you call `str(a)` or `repr(a)`. The result of `np.nonzero` is a `tuple`, which you can see visually if you notice the trailing comma immediately before the final closing parenthesis.

When an `ndarray` is displayed with `str`, dtypes that can be unambiguously shown through the data don't get an explicit dtype label. This includes `np.int_`, `np.float_` (which *always* gets a decimal point, even if just a trailing one), and `np.bool_`. Since `b` has been extracted from the tuple and has a standard dtype, it can be displayed in simplified form.

You can get an output format similar to what you see in `a` by doing `repr(b)` instead.